# How to use Selma's mapper to convert pojo with Lombok's annotations

Tags: java, lombok

I'm using [Selma](http://www.selma-java.org/) to map pojo with [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)'s annotation. Unfortunatly, it doesn't seems to work out of the box :

- https://github.com/murat8505/projectlombok/issues/812
- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/selma-java/m44hHSB-Dco/c75mVcypAgAJ

Has anyone been able to reconfigure the annotation processor to use both tool in the same maven module ?

My sample is here : https://github.com/pomverte/selma-test

Comment: I know it is not an answer you are looking for, but please take a look at xtend active annotations. With that, you get most of Lombok bultin and you can trivially implement things like Selma (even more tailored for your particular usecases). Take a look https://eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/204_activeannotations.html. On top of that, you get very expressive dialect of java, which I personally love a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to generate the Lombok + Selma classes with:

In your pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
   <build>    
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <defaultOutputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/selma
                </defaultOutputDirectory>
                <processors>
                    <processor>lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor</processor>                   
                    <processor>fr.xebia.extras.selma.codegen.MapperProcessor</processor>
                </processors>             
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>fr.xebia.extras</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selma-processor</artifactId>
                    <version>0.15</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

then run: `mvn generate-sources`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Raphael, unfortunately I haven't been able to make it work.

I've setup a simple selma project here : https://github.com/pomverte/selma-test

Would you be kind to post a Pull Request so that I can see how you've made it work ?

Cheers !